# Can't generate scaffold. Could not find rail ties gem load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, scaffold, railtie

Ruby/Rails is so confusing. I'm going through the Michael Hartl tutorial, and I get an error with the following terminal command:

```
$  rails generate scaffold Micropost content:string user_id:integer
```

gives me:

```
/Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

I really have no clue what it's asking, or why its not working. I was able to generate a scaffold earlier, and I'm in the demo_app folder in the terminal, so I'm not sure whats going on, or even what information to put on here. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#fig-demo_micropost_model   is the link, and i'm stuck at section 2.3.1

```
$bundle show
/Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /Users/johncurry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you include the output of `bundle show`?

Comment: Okay. I updated my question to include bundle show

Comment: did rvm get upgraded recently? did you build a gemset under rvm and not change back into it?  Since the issue is you can't find bundler, etc.  you can try gem install bundler  && bundle install to get the gmes back

Comment: It seems like your ruby installation (via RVM) is kinda faulty.

Comment: I just did that upon your suggestion, $rvm get stable  but the issue still persists. Although now the problem is "among 9 total gems" instead of 8.

Comment: The $gem install bundler   followed by   $bundle install    solved the problem. but.. why? do I need to do a gem install bundler   and bundle install every time I want to generate a scaffold?

Comment: it is a gem issue,  output of `rvm list` and `rvm gemset list`please.  But a quick fix should be inside the demo_app directory; `gem install bundler` and `bundle install`

Comment: no you don't need to do it every time,  something happened to your gems. Could be gemset issue, or ruby got upgraded and gems didn't move over, etc..